# d.rast -o failed after successfully imported.

Tags: gdal

I imported a geotiff raster using GUI grass, it was successful.

(Thu Nov 20 15:55:35 2014)
r.in.gdal input=C:\Users\Administrator\grassdata\kavaja\JPEG_8.tif output=JPEG_8
Projection of input dataset and current location appear to match
r.in.gdal complete. Raster map  created.
r.in.gdal complete. Raster map  created.
r.in.gdal complete. Raster map  created.
(Thu Nov 20 15:55:47 2014) Command finished (12 sec)

But when trying to display the imported image it fails.
Command 'd.rast -o map=JPEG_8@mapset_kavaja' failed

I checked from File-Manage maps and volumes, the image is listed

(Thu Nov 20 16:00:23 2014)

### g.list type=rast

raster files available in mapset :

### JPEG_8.blue  JPEG_8.green JPEG_8.red

(Thu Nov 20 16:00:24 2014) Command finished (0 sec)

Answer (score 1):

If the imported image consists of several bands, they are always extracted as separate raster maps channels (yours JPEG_8.blue JPEG_8.green JPEG_8.red)

- To combine and display these three raster maps, use the [image] button (or [d.rgb](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/d.rgb.html))
- To write out the color composite map use [r.composite](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.composite.html) from the  dialog:

[image]

or from the command line

```
r.composite red=JPEG_8.red@mapset_kavaja green=JPEG_8.green@mapset_kavaja blue=JPEG_8.blue@mapset_kavaja output=JPEG_8@mapset_kavaja')
```

Comment: This has to be done for every image imported? why is this a default option? Anyway, after i executed the proces below it stacked for hours                                           r.composite red=JPEG_8.red@mapset_kavaja green=JPEG_8.green@mapset_kavaja blue=JPEG_8.blue@mapset_kavaja output=kavaje
Creating color table for output raster map...
Writing raster map <kavaje>...

Comment: Its taking forever...